# Cleaner way to use "with torch.no_grad()" conditioned on an expression

Tags: pytorch

My code looks like:

```
if no_grad_condition:
  with torch.no_grad():
    out=network(input)
else:
  out=network(input)
```

Is there a cleaner way to do it, without duplicating the line `out=network(input)`?

I am looking for something in the spirit of:

```
  with torch.no_grad(no_grad_condition):
    out=network(input)
```

Answer (score 15):

OP here: By writing down the question, I understood where to look for the answer. According to [pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.set_grad_enabled), we can use `set_grad_enabled`:

```
  with torch.set_grad_enabled(not no_grad_condition):
    out=network(input)
```

Comment: If you need to switch the model to the test mode, add the following line: `network.train(mode=not no_grad_condition)`